# Reference for definition and more of Galois covering

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I encountered the term "galois covering" in Beauville's book on algebraic surfaces, as well as in the article "rational surfaces with many nodes" by Dolgachev et al.

However, i have not yet found a reference with the definition and some elaboration on the concept. Does anyone know a good one? (it is not in Hartshorne, right?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The laziest solution to the problem of defining (Galois) coverings in algebraic geometry  would  be to  copy *verbatim* the definition in topology, just replacing words like "topological space" by "algebraic variety".
However this doesn't work at all!
Already the simplest example $q:\mathbb C^*\to\mathbb C^*:z\mapsto z^2$ is not locally trivial downstairs in the Zariski topology.
This just means that if you delete a finite set $F$ from the copy of $\mathbb C^*$ downstairs, obtaining $U=\mathbb C^*\setminus F$, the inverse image $q^{-1}(U)$ is not a product $U\times D$  ($D=$ the variety with two elements).

So  algebraic geometers have  decided that their   coverings would  just be finite  surjective morphism $p:Y\to X$ of algebraic varieties.
For example the above map $q$ is a covering by this definition, but so is also $Q:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C:z\mapsto z^2$. This is amazing because $Q$ is not  a topological covering.
If you want to say closer to topology, you introduce *étale coverings*, which are non-ramified and flat coverings.

Coming back to the  general  definition, note that   a covering $p:Y\to X$ between irreducible varieties induces a finite field extension $p^*:k(X)\to k(Y)$ of their function fields.
This finally allows to answer  your question  :

**Definition**  A Galois covering is a covering $p:Y\to X$ between irreducible  normal varieties for which the induced field extension $p^*:k(X)\to k(Y)$ is Galois.

Comment: Of course there is a notion of Galois covering for arbitrary morphisms of schemes.

Comment: Galois coverings for schemes can be defined, but  what is a Galois covering for  an arbitrary morphism ? Anyway, I think that a classical, fairly concrete version of  Galois coverings is more useful than the most general notion for reading Beauville's beautiful book, which is expressed in the language of varieties and doesn't even mention schemes.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, thanks for the well-written answer. (as always.) I have a question. I actually bumped into the definition in an unexpected place: Milne's notes on étale cohomology. http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/lec.html  See 6.1. Your definition is mentioned in 6.2, Milne calls this generically Galois. So there seems to be different terminology around. Could you comment on which you normally find used in research papers? As mentioned in the question, i am reading a paper that uses the term, so would like to know which is most probably assumed. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Joachim: yes, Milne calls people who give the definition above  "miscreants", and I think he is right! The  definition is probably a bit too general and it seems to me (*caveat*: I'm not a specialist) that often, but not always, the definition indeed includes that a covering (Galois or not) should  be étale. Some authors helpfully use the terminology "étale covering" in order to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: @Martin: of course if you don't agree with the generality of the answer you can downvote my answer (**this** answer, of course)

Comment: I think a stronger condition is each fiber of $Y\to X$ corresponds to a Galois algebra (not necessarily field) extension. This could be the reason why Milne calls generically Galois when we have only $X=Y/G$.

Comment: Dear @Georges, Sorry to resurrect an old question, but I was thinking about this recently and assumed mistakenly that a finite (hence surjective, hence flat) map of proper smooth integral curves over a field $k$ which induces a Galois extension of function fields is a Galois covering in the strong sense of the source being an fppf $G$-torsor over the base for $G$ the Galois group of the function field extension, but based on your answer and the link to Milne's notes, this is not the case...yes? And indeed, an fppf $G$-torsor would have to be étale over the target, but certainly one can have a

Comment: Galois extension of function fields but still be ramified.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Hi Georges, you mentioned that a covering $p:Y\longrightarrow X$ would induce a finite field extension $k(X)\longrightarrow k(Y)$. How did you get that this field extension is finite?

Comment: @BehavingEarth: By the assumption (line 11)  that the morphism $p:X\to Y$ is finite.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Does $p: X\longrightarrow Y$ being finite also imply that that $Aut(X/Y)$ is finite as well?

Answer (score 0):

A gentle introduction is Lenstra's *Galois theory for schemes*, [online](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf). The original reference is [SGA1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203).

Comment: As far as I can see Lenstra doesn't define  Galois coverings (nor coverings) in these notes.

Comment: I had the same problem. @Martin would you be so kind to point out where to find the definition exactly?

Comment: Haha i heard about Edixhoven's plan to LaTeX SGA but i wasnt aware that he actually did it! Thanks for the link.